# Sonar 6.7 - Logout event filter

Tags: sonarqube

I cannot manage to catch the logout request with a servlet filter. Both `/api/authentication/logout` and `/sessions/logout` seem to be uncatchable even though the first is the one directly called when logging out and the second is the referer of several calls after logging out, including the automatic redirection toward sonar home.

How can I catch a logout event with a servlet filter ? I need to invalidate my identity provider token upon logging out.

Comment: What is this Identity Provider you need to invalidate ?

Comment: It is Crowd. I have a set of tools all connected to it, I expect (as for any SSO) to logout for all of them. Also as long as the crowd token is there, login attemps will succeed before asking me for credentials so I cannot switch user.

Comment: Are you using a SonarQube Crowd plugin ?

Comment: Yes I am, crowd-integration-client-rest 2.11.

Comment: I don't know how this plugin work, but in fact you should not need to invalidate identity provider when doing a logout.

Comment: For instance with Github, if you want to be disconnected of every applications you've used to log, you need to first disconnect you from Github, then either you want for tokens to be expired, or you do it manually

Comment: Indeed. But for the token to expire when I logout from Sonar, I need to invalidate it at some point. Or are you saying that I should never logout from sonar but from crowd directly ? Until then, users could logout from any application to be logged out from the SSO as a whole, I'd like to do that on sonar. I was able to catch `/sessions/logout` in sonar 5.6, surely there is a way to do something similar in sonar 6.7 ?

Comment: In fact I don't understand why do you need to be disconnected from crowd ? Every SSO I know don't do that (for instance on SOE, I'm using a google account, and I don't want to be disconnected from Google when disconnecting from SOR)

Comment: And I'll give an answer to this question

Comment: Very well, thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to add some hook when doing a logout from SonarQube. 
In my opinion, you should not try to hack SonarQube in order to disconnect the user from the Identity Provider when he loggout from SonarQube as he may want to use his identity to authenticate on another tool.

If for any reason you really need to do this, you should do it by using a reverse proxy.

Comment: Can you give me example how to use reverse proxy with logout? Currently I have facing the logout issue. I am using SSO Authentication as HTTP headers

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help you on that, as reverse proxy is a tool to be installed in your infrastructure, it so it depends on how it's done on your side.

Comment: OK, I will test this reverse proxy for logout api